# find unmatched data

Tags: sql

column Role _id has13 and 22 as there id, need to fetch the unmatched ID from  column cmat_customer_id.
see below data for reference"

```
SYSTEM_SERIAL_NUMBER    ROLE_ID TOTAL_ROLE_ID   CMAT_CUSTOMER_ID    CMAT_SITE_ID
200000301498    13  1   6082581 -999999
200000304907    13  1   5018171 -999999
200000273689    13  1   5008520 -999999
200000280436    13  1   5008520 -999999
451507000097    22  1   5013865 -999999
451448000036    13  1   5008621 5008622
451507000148    22  1   5013459 -999999
FB6500N120181   13  1   5002239 6019184
FB6500N120181   22  1   5002239 6019184
451507000097    22  1   5013865 5013867
451507000097    13  1   5013865 -999999
```

Expected resulet

```
SYSTEM_SERIAL_NUMBER    ROLE_ID count_ROLE_ID   CMAT_CUSTOMER_ID    CMAT_SITE_ID
200000301498    13  1   6082581 -999999
200000301498    22  1   5018171 -999999
200000304907    13  1   5018172 -999999
200000304907    22  1   5008520 -999999
451507000148    13  1   5008512 -999999
```

we do not want below result set

```
SYSTEM_SERIAL_NUMBER    ROLE_ID TOTAL_ROLE_ID   CMAT_CUSTOMER_ID    CMAT_SITE_ID
451449000141    13  1   6097038 9409647
451449000141    22  1   6097038 9409647
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where (role_id = 13 and
       not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.cmat_customer_id = t.cmat_customer_id and t2.role_id = 22)
      ) or
      (role_id = 22 and
       not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.cmat_customer_id = t.cmat_customer_id and t2.role_id = 13)
      );
```

Comment: thanks Gordon, in the table TOTAL_ROLE_ID   column is actually the count of role_id which  I used to count the total number of role_id (13 and 22) mismatch. in the above query, i get the resule set but  unable fide the total count for each role_id mismatch . I am trying to Count of mismatches where column Role ID=22 for colume cmat_customer_id is different from column Role ID=13 for column  cmat_customer_id.... I would require these fields system_serial_number,role_id,cmat_customer_id,cmat_site_id along with count